# putting `mclapply` results back onto data.frame

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply

I have a *very large* `data.frame` that I want to apply a fairly complicated function to, calculating a new column. I want to do it in parallel. This is similar to the question posted [over on the r listserve](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/09bkgq8xys/r-efficient-cbind-of-elements-from-two-lists), but the first answer is wrong and the second is unhelpful.

I've gotten everything figured out thanks to the `parallel` package, except how to put the output back onto the data frame. Here's a MWE that shows what I've got:

```
library(parallel)

# Example Data
data <- data.frame(a = rnorm(200), b = rnorm(200),  
                   group = sample(letters, 200, replace = TRUE))

# Break into list
datagroup <- split(data, factor(data$group))

# execute on each element in parallel
options(mc.cores = detectCores())
output <- mclapply(datagroup, function(x) x$a*x$b)
```

The result in `output` is a list of numeric vectors. I need them in a column that I can append to `data`.  I've been looking along the lines of `do.call(cbind, ...)`, but I have two lists with the same names, not a single list that I'm joining. `melt(output)` gets me a single vector, but its rows are not in the same order as `data`.

Comment: can't you just melt then merge? `merge(data, melt(output), by.x = 'group', by.y = 'L1')`

Comment: How can I be sure, though, that the row order in `data` is the same as the row order in `melt(output)`, after a merge?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just do `data <- do.call(rbind, mclapply(split(data, data$group), function(x){z <- x$a*x$b;x <- as.data.frame(cbind(x, newcol = z));return(x)}))`?

Comment: Well, I guess what I was missing is that I didn't think to nest everything together like that. It may not be pretty, but I think it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Converting from comment to answer..

This seems to work:

```
data <- 
  do.call(
    rbind, mclapply(
      split(data, data$group), 
       function(x){
         z <- x$a*x$b
         x <- as.data.frame(cbind(x, newcol = z))
         return(x)
         }))
rownames(data) <- seq_len(nrow(data))
head(data)
#           a          b group      newcol
#1 -0.6482428  1.8136254     a -1.17566963
#2  0.4397603  1.3859759     a  0.60949714
#3 -0.6426944  1.5086339     a -0.96959055
#4 -1.2913493 -2.3984527     a  3.09724030
#5  0.2260140  0.1107935     a  0.02504087
#6  2.1555370 -0.7858066     a -1.69383520
```

---

Since you are working with a "very large" data.frame (how large roughly?), have you considered using either `dplyr` or `data.table` for what you do? For a large data set, performance may be even better with one of these than with `mclapply`. The equivalent would be:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(newcol = a * b)

library(data.table) 
setDT(data)[, newcol := a*b, by=group]
```

Comment: I use `dplyr` constantly, and would love use it in this application. The problem is that the function I am running is much more complicated than `*`, so I want to parallelize it. Also, I have a 12-core processor, so why not? Hopefully Hadley and Romain will parallelize `dplyr` soon. https://github.com/romainfrancois/parallelGroupBy

Comment: @gmacfarlane, fair enough. Would still be interesting to compare the performances.

Comment: applying my function (which itself uses `dplyr` `do()` commands) directly to the data frame was estimated to take about 4 hours (going off of the `do()` progress bar. In parallel, it took about 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

A bit dated, but this might help.

rbind will kill you in terms of performance if you have many splits.

It's much faster to use the unsplit function.

```
results <- mclapply( split(data, data$group), function(x) x$a*x$b) 

resultscombined <- unsplit (results, data$group)

data$newcol <-  resultscombined
```

Yeah there's a memory hit so depends on what you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the mean by group using a multicore process:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- group_by(iris, Species)
indices <- attr(x,"indices")
labels <- attr(x,"labels") 

require(parallel)
result <- mclapply(indices,  function(indx){
                   data <- slice(iris, indx + 1)
                   ## Do something...
                   mean(data$Petal.Length)
                   }, mc.cores =2)

 out <- cbind(labels,mean=unlist(result))
 out
 ##      Species  mean
 ## 1     setosa 1.462
 ## 2 versicolor 4.260
 ## 3  virginica 5.552
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently unable to download the `parallel` package to my computer. Here I post a solution that works for my usual setup using the `snow` package for computation in parallel.

The solution simply orders the data.frame at the beginning, then merges the output list calling `c()`. See below:

```
library(snow)
library(rlecuyer)

# Example data
data <- data.frame(a = rnorm(200), b = rnorm(200),  
                   group = sample(letters, 200, replace = TRUE))
data <- data[order(data$group),]

# Cluster setup
clNode <- list(host="localhost")
localCl <- makeSOCKcluster(rep(clNode, 2))
clusterSetupRNG(localCl, type="RNGstream", seed=sample(0:9,6,replace=TRUE))
clusterExport(localCl, list=ls())

# Break into list
datagroup <- split(data, factor(data$group))

output <- clusterApply(localCl, datagroup, function(x){ x$a*x$b })

# Put back and check
data$output <- do.call(c, output)
data$check <- data$a*data$b

all(data$output==data$check)

# Stop cluster
stopCluster(localCl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @beginneR and our common love of `dplyr`, I did some more fiddling and think the best way to make this happen is

```
 rbind_all( mclapply(split(data, data$group), fun(x) as.data.frame(x$a*x$b)))
```